# Load a locale from /usr/local/share/locale in OS X

Tags: macos, postgresql

While importing a PostgreSQL database in OS X 10.10, I got a error like "invalid locale name: en_US.utf8". I went to `/usr/share/locale` and copied the folder `en_US.UTF-8` as `en_US.utf8`. Ok, problem solved.

But I know this solution will not work in OS X 10.11 due to that "rootless mode". I'll not be able to modify `/usr/share/locale`.

Is there any way to load this folder from `/usr/local/share/locale`? I tried to copy `en_US.utf8` to that directory and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you disable SiP (rootless)

Comment: No, and I prefer not doing it unless there is no other way around. System Integrity Protection is nice overall.

Comment: you can disable, then do your stuff, then re-enable it.

Comment: I would use that as last resort. I'm not sure if Apple will be resetting /usr/share/locale in the next updates, forcing me to repeat the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution now is to simply replace the string "en_US.utf8" with "en_US.UTF-8" in the dump file. Since that file is compressed in my case (hence binary format), it was necessary to keep the same number of characters in the original line. So I remove a couple of white-spaces, transforming

```
(...) LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.utf8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.utf8' (...)
```

into

```
(...) LC_COLLATE= 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE= 'en_US.UTF-8' (...)
```

A perl command to do that in my importing script was

```
perl -pi -e "s/LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.utf8'/LC_COLLATE= 'en_US.UTF-8'/g" myDumpFilePath
perl -pi -e "s/LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.utf8'/LC_CTYPE= 'en_US.UTF-8'/g" myDumpFilePath
```

Comment: #taketheblowonthehead similar problem, but I was trying to restore a 47GB PG_DATA directory

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (macos 10.14):

```
sudo localedef -i /usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8 /usr/local/share/locale/en_US.utf8
sudo cp /usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE /usr/local/share/locale/en_US.utf8/
```